# Jquery binding woes

Tags: jquery, binding

I've read a number of explanations but it seems I just can't grasp the concept of binding. In the following code how would I make 'this' refer to the object rather than the element that called the 'search' function?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 >
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="inpt">
<script>
obj = {
  theElement: null,
  func1: function(inpt) {
    this.theElement = $(inpt);
    this.theElement.keyup(this.search);
  },
  search: function(e) {
    alert(this);  //'this' refers to the input element (#inpt) but I want it to refer to 'obj'
  }
};
obj.func1('#inpt');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that makes some sense...

Comment: I consider both (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795794/jquery-binding-woes/4795839#4795839 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795794/jquery-binding-woes/4795846#4795846) answers below to be fab answers to my question. I have gone with the $.proxy solution which was suggested in both. I have marked T.J. Crowder's as accepted due to the interesting links 'Closures are not complicated' and 'You must remember this'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

#### 1. Use your own closure:

```
obj = {
  theElement: null,
  func1: function(inpt) {
    var self = this;
    this.theElement = $(inpt);
    this.theElement.keyup(function() {
        self.search();
    });
  },
  search: function(e) {
    alert(this);  //'this' refers to the input element (#inpt) but I want it to refer to 'obj'
  }
};
```

More reading: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

**Edit**: Although as [patrick points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795794/jquery-binding-woes/4795839#4795839), you already have a reference to it in `obj` and so technically don't need `self`. The above is more of a general solution (particularly when you use factory functions rather than singleton objects).

#### 2. Use one jQuery creates for you:

...via [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
obj = {
  theElement: null,
  func1: function(inpt) {
    this.theElement = $(inpt);
    this.theElement.keyup(jQuery.proxy(this.search, this));
  },
  search: function(e) {
    alert(this);  //'this' refers to the input element (#inpt) but I want it to refer to 'obj'
  }
};
```

More reading: [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
    this.theElement.keyup(this.search);
```

to this:

```
    this.theElement.keyup(function() {
        obj.search();
    }
```

or this:

```
    this.theElement.keyup($.proxy(this.search,this))
```

...which uses [`jQuery.proxy()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to return a function that will invoke `search()` with the proper `this` value.

There is also [the `.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) that can be used to bind context and parameters to a function, but it isn't widely supported yet.